# Stream and Filter using Functional Programming for Server object in List<Server>

Tags: java-8, functional-programming

I have two `List<Server>` current and `List<Server>` serverList but I want to filter out Server from current which are already **present** in serverList.

Now the Unique based on which it will check is `List<IPAddress>` which is inside both of above list.

IPAddress POJO has two fields String `ipaddress, boolean primary`

List has multiple secondary ip but one unique primary ip therefore we need to filter out based on this primary ip and we can check only if it is boolean true to know if its primary ip.

I think this will make a very complex stream filter logic therefore I need help I tried but I am not expert in functional programming.

```
serverList.stream().filter(new Predicate<? extends Server>() {

                })
```

> Error: The method filter(Predicate) in the type
>   Stream is not applicable for the arguments (new Predicate(){})

Server POJO has getters and setters same as IPAddress. List is inside this Server POJO as getter and setter.

```
public class Server {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="id")
    public Integer id;


    @OneToMany (mappedBy = "server",cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private List<IPAddress> ipaddresses;

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }


    public void setIpaddresses(List<IPAddress> ipaddresses) {
        this.ipaddresses = ipaddresses;
    }

    public List<IPAddress> getIpaddresses() {
        return ipaddresses;
    }
}
```

IPAddress POJO

```
public class IPAddress {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="ID")
    public Integer id;

    @Column(name="ipaddress")
    private String ipaddress;

    @Column(name="primaryIP")
    private boolean primary;

    @ManyToOne
    @JsonIgnore
    @JoinColumn(name = "server_id")
    private Server server;


    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getIpaddress() {
        return ipaddress;
    }

    public void setIpaddress(String ipaddress) {
        this.ipaddress = ipaddress;
    }

    public boolean isPrimary() {
        return primary;
    }

    public void setPrimary(boolean primary) {
        this.primary = primary;
    }

    public Server getServer() {
        return server;
    }

    public void setServer(Server server) {
        this.server = server;
    }


}
```

Comment: [Please provide minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: It is still not complete verifiable example. There are still unclear questions in my head like what Server class looks like, how to compare it? Based on some property or object equality?

Comment: @Emre is it okay now or something still missing which I didn't provided?

Comment: @Emre Resolving this problem might give me a little edge on functional programming in java using Lambda expressions

Comment: It looks better now, this way the users can understand and represent problem domain

Comment: @Plootus Do we have same primary IP address in two servers? Is it possible? In real world it is NOT.

Comment: @RavindraRanwala no its not possible where did you see it in my question ?

Comment: @Plootus No it has not been stated explicitly in the question, hence I just wanted to confirm it before updating my answer. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is actually quite simple.

First, add a method in Server to get its primary address:

```
public String getPrimaryIpAddress() {
    return ipaddresses.stream()
        .filter(IPAddress::isPrimary)
        .findAny()
        .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("there should be a primary address")
        .getIpaddress();
}
```

Then create a Set of primary addresses

```
List<Server> serverList = ...
Set<String> primaryIpAddresses = serverList.stream()
    .map(Server::getPrimaryIpAddress)
    .collect(Collectors.toSet());
```

Then filter the list of servers:

```
List<Server> currrent = ...

List<Server> filtered = current.stream()
    .filter(s -> !primaryIpAddresses.contains(s.getPrimaryIpAddress()))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: `IPAddress::isPrimary`

Comment: can you give me a little explanation why you are filtering in getters of Server method ?

Comment: Because you want a method that returns the primary address, among all the addresses, of a server. I'm not filtering "in getters". I addd a method to get the primary address of the server. What's the issue? Why would you *not* add such a method? What's so strange about it in your eyes?

Comment: because there is no such fields as Primary address in Server POJO rather it's in IPAddress. Server can get List<IPAddress> which has multiple secondary but uinque primary for each server

Comment: A method doesn't have to return a field. A method returns whatever it wants/needs to return. This method's responsibility is to find the primary address of the server and to return it.

Comment: @JBNizet you filtered serverList from current or current from serverList? What you did in filtered list?

Comment: Read the code. On what do I call `filter()` in the last snippet? What do you conclude? What is being filtered?

Comment: I am filtering serverList and update this list on server not current. More Approapriate is serverList - current(substract). Removing all server of current from serverList then update

Comment: Your question asks exactly the inverse. i quote: *I want to filter out Server **from current** which are already present in serverList*. Anyway, if you know how to do one, you know how to do the other. Just replace current by serverList and vice-versa.

Comment: You'll learn by practicing, reading the javadoc, and reading the code of your more experienced collegues.

Comment: will check with test cases first then make your answer as accepted. Thanks a lot!